# Compiling perf using buildroot

Tags: linux, perf, buildroot

Buildroot fails, when building perf with the following error:

```
>>> perf custom Building
Your kernel version is too old and does not have the perf tool.
At least kernel 2.6.31 must be used.
package/pkg-generic.mk:184: recipe for target recipe for target '[..]/buildroot/output/build/perf-custom/.stamp_built' failed
make: *** [ [..]/buildroot/output/build/perf-custom/.stamp_built] Error 1
```

The kernel source is in a seperate directory and has got version 4.0.0. So. the error is not true.

```
  │ │    [*] Linux Kernel                                                 │ │  
  │ │          Kernel version (Custom override kernel source)  --->       │ │  
  │ │    (linux/linux-kernel) PATH of custom override kernel              │ │
```

The target is an armv7

How could I fix the buildroot config, or set the correct version?
(If this is not possible, how to build perf manually?)

Comment: I believe this has been fixed in recent Buildroot versions, because it now uses the perf sources directly from the kernel sources.

Comment: What Buildroot version is this? We have afaik never had a "Custom override kernel source" option, so it looks like it is some fork. Can you try again with the upstream 2017.02.3 / 2017.05 release?